# How can I send voice clips on Facebook Chat using the desktop interface?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'd like to send voice clips on Facebook Chat using the desktop interface. I know mobile users can do it, but is there any way for desktops?

Answer (score 1):

Untested. [Here](http://www.askmefast.com/How_can_I_attach_a_voice_clip_on_facebook_chat-qna5918989.html#q3143035), unfortunately undated, has:

> You should first go full screen chat with the person you want to send the voice clip and then there is a small button near send button if you click it you will get it.